# I am developing video chat application with laravel and opentok. But I am stuck in implementing a way to let users call each other

Tags: android, laravel, push-notification, opentok

I have been trying to build video chat application using opentok. When User 1 calls User 2, I want User 2 to be notified that User 1 is calling.

I have made this work using Pusher and Laravel Echo using Laravel Broadcasting service. But I don't know if this is the best way to do it.Also, we need to integrate it to the mobile and I am not sure if Pusher and Echo are going work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using another service like Pusher is probably the best option. OpenTok does not currently provide a calling type API, it is instead based on rooms (sessions).

One alternative using just OpenTok would be to have the participants both connect to a session and have the call action be when you call publish(). Then when you receive the streamCreated event on the other side you can treat that like the participant trying to call you. Answering the call is subscribing to the created stream and publishing back the other way.

Depending on your application this might not really work though, eg. if you have lots of different participants all being able to call one another then you will need to connect to lots of different sessions at the same time.